# Aurora Serverless - tables are empty after successful insert

Tags: mysql-5.7, aws-aurora

I have MySQL 5.7.12 running on Aurora Serverless, and I've created a database with a table:

```
mysql> show create database tpcc\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Database: tpcc
Create Database: CREATE DATABASE `tpcc` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
mysql> show create table customer\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: customer
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `c_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `c_d_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `c_w_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `c_first` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_middle` char(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_last` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_street_1` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_street_2` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_city` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_state` char(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_zip` char(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_phone` char(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_since` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_credit` char(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_credit_lim` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_discount` decimal(4,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_balance` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_ytd_payment` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_payment_cnt` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_delivery_cnt` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_data` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_w_id`,`c_d_id`,`c_id`),
  KEY `c_w_id` (`c_w_id`,`c_d_id`,`c_last`,`c_first`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I then insert 30,000 rows in `customer`:

```
insert into warehouse (w_id,w_ytd,w_tax,w_name,w_street_1,w_street_2,w_city,w_state,w_zip) values ("1","3000000.00",".12","UUT8ryfW9","0xxVB3Bf3gXhwuWC","ieQILn5Ip78WsgE0","qA4QpGIfKA1jdI5","YZ","421211111");
$ head ../customer.sql
insert into customer (c_id,c_d_id,c_w_id,c_first,c_middle,c_last,c_street_1,c_street_2,c_city,c_state,c_zip,c_phone,c_since,c_credit,c_credit_lim,c_discount,c_balance,c_ytd_payment,c_payment_cnt,c_delivery_cnt,c_data) values
("1","1","1","Uvp7TiuDJqpjRtn","OE","BARBARBAR","LanIkNplm4vvI","ev2gqIygqZmLvEFpEy","tLRMSjvRsJA","EW","794211111","9160426292840508","2021-08-17 10:24:40","GC","50000","0.49","-10.0","10.0","1","0","y5diSkn826p6lRI969nVpIuevzCCFLwWoIIA3bPyXt06qxoRlw3S5by2tksPJf5AfQMwzK0lWWIHXieHbMDLqVFYacnMdLn1IZU5bgDIQb2JY2h2lBLMAHgd0g8HEud3N31Nay84Pm9cO32IqoTrXR8tcCiaRnUJOuxKg6fopE4bzCQ4A8njCvPxVX0XiYPp7I5qzLyLqmHDsieYfWUHwimAn2kUMg9A0xMugsBL2X5xQ5n5hihTJGZriZz0eQWTWczvwbvfB4XfMhwfnneCHFVqkYtY7RpSgxVcKI2KlLDkprb8dQgkmYpRzjcCOMcpTt2JOGIC7OCEPMLp1c90BA0Fovc9uP6X20TA1xPZh7KZ7oLdS"),
("2","1","1","P7EMzi4gjY","OE","BARBAROUGHT","uCh4Ua4h9YJ","l4JGxPsECW","vb54Axqphauv7h5","5J","336811111","5501919375897530","2021-08-17 10:24:40","GC","50000","0.47","-10.0","10.0","1","0","BtCUBb5QV8p8J0TqK5CajJpHiCFUIv3lPbMz7GaNjeaQ9mm80AMxSalFr8nCn0dyqHvThIhRjZ6HaCLDBR5nkOOLJsedYrwrC0948NTYuIYfrEbRa2nWgx56C4cgXXhLg1AO5DTaKTxvaFiAVlA7102nZooSqStrfK2sNo024PP5TFBqirvwNVK2CuasQJiIjH0xWzdXcVsRfu1TGCxlpMLJLM4cValCuaqh12sVVaju8iyneeqZaHSC4ZfcGEXsZhNrsYxOF8Wr4ZanOEJOvxFZFppr8Yo58EV4WvEWhYcQt1FclQ3IGvpgCzlEsf6wemT8NbZBaoIUamfK6xAOC5ghtYjItTTjcYkmsTyikDMKU40mnHtJNVMpMsNWZRV2GWGSxjvlLRJUbncjbo8PX3OXuhzR0l0hjmEXgsXm0BZH5XDr7zuvNzgT3mzM1Ehgxcb"),
...

mysql> select count(*) from customer;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    30000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But after I log out and back in, the table is empty. How is that possible?

***Edit***

Just a quick edit to say that I did in fact issue an explicit commit after the insert!

***Edit***

As suggested by *matigo*, I logged in and checked my tables. This is where it gets weird (and scary):

- Yesterday I created several tables and inserted rows successfully.
- When I logged out/in, they were all empty.
- I inserted rows into the `customer` table, logged in from another terminal and saw the data from that session.
- Today, I first checked another database on the same instance; the tables contain data as expected.
- This is the strange thing: the `customer` table contains data, and the rest in that database are empty.

The reason I find this scary is that it looks like I can't trust my database to be consistent - what if it has been discarding data without notifying me all along?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but how many times did you query the data *after* reconnecting? Reason I ask is because an Aurora Serverless instance will auto shutdown when there are zero active connections. It generally takes about 3~4 seconds to come back online. During that period, errors and/or null data sets will be returned (depending on how you're connecting) 

Comment: @matigo Not silly at all - I only queried briefly, with select count(*). The funny thing, now you mention it, is that once, when I connected two sessions, I could see the data from the other session, even after logging off from the first. I'll check again.