# insert does not work in aurora serverless?

Tags: mysql-5.6, aws-aurora

This is in continuation of [Aurora Serverless - tables are empty after successful insert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/aurora-serverless-tables-are-empty-after-successful-insert), which I asked yesterday. I create a separate question to highlight what seems to be the real problem: I have manually created a database, with a table:

```
create database tpcc;
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `i_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `i_im_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_name` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_price` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i_data` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I then insert 1 row into item:

```
mysql> insert into item (i_id,i_im_id,i_name,i_price,i_data) values
    -> ("1","5009","r0jYVFV1KA6NBW","82.38","TOIgGQfuVK2o407cpUlGkxXByf4Oz");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from item;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Then I log out and back in:

```
mysql> select count(*) from item;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I can't see there is anything wrong with the SQL, and I have, for reference, tested doing the exact same on a classic MySQL, where it works as expected; so it must be Aurora serverless, somehow. Are there any parameters that would induce this behaviour?

***Edit***

I have found, if not a solution, then at least a workaround: `flush tables;` preserves the data. Why that is so, I don't understand. To my mind, if I have committed the transactions, then the data should stay after I leave the session.

Comment: Have you tried `commit`ting?

Comment: Yes - any way, it is set to autocommit.